# DB2 LUW Query Optimization - IXSCAN timerons greater than total timerons

Tags: db2, tuning

Sorry - I feel like this is a newb question, but I can't find anything on it.
In optimizing a query, I was able to *apparently* reduce the total timerons from 3,700 to 38.
However, on closer examination of the explain plan for the optimized query, I see one IXSCAN that reports 3,707.97 timerons, while the total is still reported as 38.61!

I'm not super familiar with DB2 LUW, and was wondering how this could be.  Even with parallelism, I would not think we could get much smaller than, say, 1/4 of the largest #. Surely not 1/10th. (?)

This is DB2 LUW 9.5 on AIX.  Very plain-vanilla installation for testing environment. No HA, no partitioning, nothing like that.

[image: Explain plan from Control Center - Command Editor]

Comment: Did you try using `db2exfmt` to display the plan?

Comment: I have, now :-)  It appears to give the same results. I'm having trouble figuring out how to attach a file, so here are the highlights: RETURN: (Return Result)
  Cumulative Total Cost:   38.6147                                                      IXSCAN: (Index Scan)
  Cumulative Total Cost:   3707.97

Comment: Normally this should not be so. There is a chance that the table and index statistics are out of sync (the `db2exfmt` report would show the respective data at the end). There is also a chance that there may be a bug in the explain facility. Are you using the most recent fix pack?

Comment: Any traction on this?

Comment: Sorry - been a crazy couple days.  I think you might be onto something about the statistics.  Let me check it out and get back to you.  The FP won't be the most recent (it's a client-model), but it should have been updated from the base.  The main thing I think I was looking for is confirmation that those results are crazy and not to be trusted, and it sounds like I'm getting that.  Thanks :-)  I'll check the statistics and update the thread.

Comment: Yeah - it's DB2 9.5 Fixpack 3a. I regored and ran statistics on table and indexes. I'm sure it could use some updating.  Again, though, I think that the main thing I wanted to verify is that the result is crazy.  Knowing that, I can make a more informed decision about the query.  I actually re-wrote it and am now getting a legit 25 timerons.  I think I'm good.  Thanks for the responses :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just want to tie this off.
As was suggested in the comments, this simply should not be so. It must have been a bug in the level of DB2 I was using.